# .scala.html file reloading again and again

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-2.10, playframework-2.2, scala-template

command prompt showing,

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/winoria/winoria/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/winoria/winoria/target/scala-2.10/classes...

--- (RELOAD) ---

[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/winoria/winoria/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/winoria/winoria/target/scala-2.10/classes...

--- (RELOAD) ---

[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/winoria/winoria/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/winoria/winoria/target/scala-2.10/classes...
```

on cancelling execution

```
[warn] Canceling execution...
[ERROR] Failed to construct terminal; falling back to unsupported
java.io.IOException: Unrecognized stty code: 
    at jline.internal.TerminalLineSettings.<init>(TerminalLineSettings.java:59)
    at jline.UnixTerminal.<init>(UnixTerminal.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at jline.TerminalFactory.getFlavor(TerminalFactory.java:168)
    at jline.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:81)
    at jline.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:159)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anon$1.run(MainLoop.scala:19)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: There's been issues like that before in Play (though these should be long fixed now) where files with non UTF-8 characters would behave this way. Does your file have any non UTF-8 characters?

Comment: i paste its code in another .scala.html file,and rename it with older name and delete the older html file, then it runs perfectly

Comment: I suggest you (a) post that as an answer and accept it, to mark the question closed and help future visitors, (b) report a bug on Play on Github if this occurs with the latest release of Play.

Comment: @robin Green , yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got a solution.
my older file`(wall.scala.html)` getting this problem.
so i delete it, and create a new file with the same name`(wall.scala.html)`, and paste the old code in the new one and now this works fine.